# How to import data into a Salesforce sandbox from a Snowflake database or AWS S3 by API and Python code?

Tags: python-3.x, salesforce, sandbox, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, salesforce-service-cloud

I want to load data into a Salesforce sandbox from a Snowflake database (or from AWS S3) using Python.

Could you please let me know of any way to connect to Salesforce sandbox from an AWS EC2 instance?

Comment: Would like to suggest you post your question with analysis from your end

Comment: Have you taken a look at some of the partner connectors to Snowflake - Check out Fivetran, I know they have a salesforce, and aws connector.

Answer (score 1):

We used to do this at a company I worked for in the past. We used a combination of [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) (for orchestration) and the [Simple-Salesforce](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/) as the python library.